# What are the options, without libraries, to modify an user submitted image before posting to server?

Tags: javascript, forms, image, compression, submit

I'm struggling to understand how this can be done.
I have a form that consists of text and an image.
I don't want to post the user selected image as is (this could lead to many MB of data uploads). So I need to crop / resize / compress the image client side using javascript.
I already know how to do this with canvas etc. The problem is submitting the new resulting image instead of the user selected original one.
I checked the formData stuff and you can't delete the user input (it works only on some browsers).
So my thought would be getting all the user input from the form in javascript, manipulate the file, create a new form with formData and send it to the server.
However I can't understand how this can be done. I tried the last option described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript and it doesn't even do anything, meaning my code doesn't intercept anything at all, console is empty no event fired. And besides that I am not even sure that's the correct way to go.
Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Why not use `canvas.toDataUrl()` to convert the new image to base64 and then upload it?

Comment: I am using canvas.toDataUrl() to convert the image. The problem is how do you replace the original image that was selected in the form with the resulting base64 one before uploading it to the server after the user hit the submit button.

Comment: You're just looking at it in the wrong way. Don't "submit the form" as a regular "let the browser do this for me" form submission. Instead, send an ajax request with whatever values you need from the form (but not the original file field) and put your newly created image in the data sent.

Comment: Yes I am doing like that. So my guess would be submit the form. In the script get the entries from formData (let's say postData submitted values) and create a new formData (processedData) with all the text input. Manipulate the image and append to the new formData then send to server.

Comment: It'd be better if you could provide a code sample of what you're doing and where the problem lies.